# Tail probability of normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Is a normal distribution is also a long-tail distribution?

The definition of long-tail distribution I used is: $\bar\Phi(x-t)\sim\bar\Phi(x),x\rightarrow\infty$ for any $t\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

I have $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\bar\Phi(x-t)-\bar\Phi(x)=0$.

Comment: $a_n \sim b_n$ as $n\to\infty$ means that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. This is not the same as $a_n-b_n\to 0$. The convergence $F(x-t)-F(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ holds for any CDF since it converges to $1$ at infinity. But this does not mean that each CDF is long-tailed.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the definition. If $t$ is an any constant from $R$,  is normal distribution is a long-tail distribution?

Comment: No. Every long-tailed distribution is heavy-tailed. Normal distribution is not heavy-tailed.